# How can I get two different Sub Buttons to see each other

Tags: vb.net

I need the inputs of all salesPerID to correpond to each ID in the salesIDListBox.
I Then have an addButton that needs to store these values. 
Then a different createButton is to create a report that shows each ID and its corresponding sale along with a total of all 5 sales that were inputted in a totalSalesTextBox.

I am so lost.  I know I have issues with my variables not being declared because they are in different Subs.  I just need some help so I can see how to make this all work.

```
Public Class MainForm
    Private Sub exitButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles exitButton.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
    Private Sub MainForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        salesIDListBox.Items.Add(101)
        salesIDListBox.Items.Add(112)
        salesIDListBox.Items.Add(203)
        salesIDListBox.Items.Add(301)
        salesIDListBox.Items.Add(302)
        salesIDListBox.SelectedIndex = 0

    End Sub
    Private Sub addButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles addButton.Click


        Static salesPerID(5) As Integer
        Dim total As Integer
        Dim subscript As Integer
        subscript = salesIDListBox.SelectedIndex
        salesTextBox.Text = salesPerID(subscript).ToString("C0")

        Integer.TryParse(salesTextBox.Text, total)
        subscript = salesIDListBox.SelectedIndex

        salesPerID(subscript) += total

    End Sub
    Private Sub createButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles createButton.Click

        totalSalesTextBox.Text = salesPerID(0).ToString
        totalSalesTextBox.Text = salesPerID(1).ToString
        totalSalesTextBox.Text = salesPerID(2).ToString
        totalSalesTextBox.Text = salesPerID(3).ToString
        totalSalesTextBox.Text = salesPerID(4).ToString

        totalSalesTextBox.Text = total
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare these variables outside the sub (fields).

```
 Dim total As Integer
 Dim subscript As Integer
 Dim salesPerID(5) As Integer
 Private Sub addButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles addButton.Click
   subscript = salesIDListBox.SelectedIndex
   salesTextBox.Text = salesPerID(subscript).ToString("C0")
   Integer.TryParse(salesTextBox.Text, total)
   subscript = salesIDListBox.SelectedIndex
   salesPerID(subscript) += total
 End Sub
 Private Sub createButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles createButton.Click
        totalSalesTextBox.Text = salesPerID(0).ToString
        totalSalesTextBox.Text = salesPerID(1).ToString
        totalSalesTextBox.Text = salesPerID(2).ToString
        totalSalesTextBox.Text = salesPerID(3).ToString
        totalSalesTextBox.Text = salesPerID(4).ToString

        totalSalesTextBox.Text = total
End Sub
```